# Can some one explain the end of my fibonacci code?

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

I was creating fibonacci and my original return was "return (num - 1) + (num - 2)" but dont work, some one sugested to call the function "return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2)" and it worked, my question is why?

Code in anex

```
function fibonacci(num) {
    if (num < 2) {
        return num;

    } else {
        return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a recursive function. You're calling `fibonacci` inside itself.

Comment: Just to add on. The recursive function should have a valid `condition` to terminate. In the above case, the 1st `if` otherwise it would go in `infinite` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the MDN, "The act of a function calling itself, recursion is used to solve problems that contain smaller sub-problems. A recursive function can receive two inputs: a base case (ends recursion) or a recursive case (resumes recursion)." Thanks for the pacience to explain Parag Diwan.